# How to find people who have deceased through SQL from a table?

Tags: mysql

I have two doubts:

I have a table as follows:

```
AUTHOR
(
authorID int NOT NULL,
authName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
authSurname varchar(255),
authPlaceOfBirth varchar(255),
authDOB date(),
authDoD varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (authorID)
)
```

Now, I want to find the authors who have died. That is, if the value of DoD exists in the table, then they have died. How to do this? That is, a particular value in a column exists?

Something like this:

```
SELECT authName
FROM AUTHOR
WHERE authDoD is not NULL?
```

Second, I have two tables as follows:

```
TABLE inventory_genre
{
genreID int NOT NULL,
inventoryID int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (genreID,inventoryID)
}
TABLE INVENTORY 
{
inventoryID int NOT NULL,
title varchar(255),
wholesale int,
markup int,
qtyinStock int, 
Discount int, 
PRIMARY KEY (inventoryID)
}
```

I want to list all the genres that have no associated titles in the inventory. I know I have to subtract but I am not able to come up with it exactly. Please guide me in the right direction!

Comment: is this a homework exercise? i don't see an effort from your side.

Comment: I would tend to expect the answer is already available to you in the preceeding part of the same book?

Comment: @Martin, there are solved questions in the book and then there are some unsolved questions. This is part of the unsolved question and as I wrote above, I know how to solve it and I have written the approach too, but I don't know how to translate it in SQL. For example, for deceased question, I know, the answer will be the authors whose date of death exist but I don't know how to check if a value exists in a particular table. I searched on SO but I found answers to check if a particular record exists in the complete table but not how to check if a particular value exists in a column.

Comment: Why on Earth would you use `VARCHAR (255)` for `DoD`, yet the `DoB` has the proper `DATE` datatype?

Comment: @Siyual, yes, correct. I will correct this mistake of mine. Thanks for pointing out. :)

Comment: Also, please do not ask two completely unrelated questions in the same post.  Make a separate question for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the criteria you are describing in the first question, but either

```
select * from author where authDOB is not null;
```

or

```
select * from author where authDOB = 'some value that I dont know';
```

For the second one, you could use `exists` or `in` with a nested select:

```
select * from genre where id not in (select genreId from inventory_genre);
```

Comment: Your answer beat me by a few minutes so I decided to reference yours for the Part 2 solution. Neat and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1**

Think about it logically:

- you're looking for people who are referenced by what?

  - By their death.
- How do you know they're dead?

  - Because a certain field in the table has been filled in.
- Can you quantify this?

  - Yes, the value of their death exists.

So, yon can construct an SQL search that looks in the table of `Authors` for rows (people) where the column (`authDoD`) value is not nothing/null.

> As a note for a perfect world you should have IS NULL set in the column authDoD so that if no value is set the column row value is `NULL` and easier to handle in queries.

SQL (assuming column can be empty but *not* Null):

```
SELECT * FROM authors WHERE authDoD > ''
```

SQL (assuming column *can* only be null unless dead):

```
SELECT * FROM authors WHERE authDoD IS NOT NULL
```

**Part 2**

You want to return a negative search, a search that turns up no results, so find each genre which does not feature in any inventory table row.

While I'm about to write a longer answer for this, [the answer just posted by Tobb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37570385/3536236) does exactly what you need.

Also note that you should ideally have an INDEX on your ID columns to make traversing them smoother and faster.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, you could use

```
SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE authDoD IS NOT NULL;
```

This would SELECT the deceased people

Answer (score -1):

Your first problem is solved, if you check for `authorDoD > ''`. It will evaluate to false if there's `NULL` or the empty string `''`.

To solve your second problem you could just `JOIN` your tables, since the `inventoryID` isn't allowed to be `NULL`.

```
JOIN INVENTORY i ON (inventory_genre.inventoryID = i.inventoryID)
```

After that you can check the existence of an title like above with `title > ''`.

Comment: thanks for the help. In the second query, if I check for the existence of `title > ' '`, how will that help me get me the genres that have no titles?

Comment: Well you can just check if `title IS NULL OR title = ''`. It's the other way around. :)